# How to make logging.properties and commons-logging.properties property files working?

Tags: java, java.util.logging, apache-commons-logging

I have two property files in my default package (I'm using NetBeans):

commons-logging.properties with property:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
```

and logging.properties with:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I'm getting INFO level messages in output. What i'm doing wrong? I also haven't found any information about JDK  configuration, just example as above.

Comment: I don't know about netbeans, but for eclipse, despite you can add a logging.properties to a web server (expecting it to overwrite the default configuration files) what really happens is that the server runtime points to an explicit logging.properties that IS NOT THE SAME, so you must open the referenced file directly and make your changes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have `.level=SEVERE` appended on the last line, it should just like this:-

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you calling the java?

Are you putting -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/logging.properties in your java command?

If not, it would ignore your logging.properties and log everything.

.level=ALL on a line of it's own is used as a global level, e.g. : -

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
.level=SEVERE
mypackage.level=INFO
```

would only log INFO messages from mypackage and SEVERE from everything else.

Comment: I have this defined in the netbeans run command and it's not working. Where is logging.properties? Is it a part of the jar output? Is it in the dist directory? This is all very unclear :( also watch out for the typo in the command, logging is missing the 'o'

Comment: /logging.properties is a file on the file system (you would have to put the full pathname).